# Eclipse Plugin - textfield in menu

Tags: eclipse, textbox, eclipse-plugin, textfield

I am working on Eclipse plugin and would like to add textfield in menu (in plugin.xml)...

```
<command
    commandId="smth.somewhere.someCommand"
    id="smth.somewhere.someCommand"
    style="push">
</command>
```

This would create button... but how do I create textbox/textfield?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen a menu with a text field... Also I've never seen an UI guideline which would recommend you to do so, since menus are for command selection, not for data entry.

Comment: It's true but would really like to do this... sometimes you can see search or filter option there...

Comment: Is it possible to show some dialog with input on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a text field in a toolbar using `org.eclipse.ui.menus` and the <control ... /> element instead of <command ... />

You cannot put a text field **in** a menu in eclipse.

You can pop up a dialog from the command's handler using JFace dialogs, like `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openQuestion(Shell, String, String)`